# Cycle Through Listbox on Click Event

Tags: vb.net

I have a listbox with items, and when I press a button I would like to go to the next item. I'm having a horrible brain fart and have been for quite some time.

```
for x = 0 to listbox1.items.count - 1
     label1.text = listbox1.items.item(x)
     x += 1
next
```

Probably a dumb mistake on my part :( 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put the code inside the loop into the `Click` event handler.

```
Private listItemIndex As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If listItemIndex < ListBox1.Items.Length Then
        Label1.Text = ListBox1.Items(listItemIndex).ToString()
        listItemIndex += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

And, should you ever need to loop over all items as in your original code, always prefer the `For Each` loop to the indexed loop. It is more concise and more direct and hence (arguably) more idiomatic.

```
For Each item In ListBox1.Items
    Label1.Text = item.ToString()
Next
```

/EDIT: Pay attention to enable `Option Strict` everywhere in your project unless there's a compelling reason not to. This makes the compiler recognize a lot more potential problems for you. It also means that the above code needs an explicit cast (or call to `ToString`) since `ListBox.Items` returns `Object`s.

Comment: +1 After re-reading I think this may be what the OP is after.